# Error with packages \hyperref, \subfig and \subcaption

Tags: hyperref, subcaption, subfig

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.3in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    [...]
    
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:cape}
    \centering
    t_{rise_{A}} = t_{rise_{B}} \times V_A / V_B
    \end{equation}
    
    [...]

    Inoltre sono stati misurati dei tempi di salita  $t_{rise}$  in linea con quanto previsto dalla relazione \ref{eq:cape}.
    \end{document}
```

This is my code. The compiler doesn't read the reference and it gives as error an undefined control sequence: "\reserved@b ->\T@ref

```
l.186 ...con quanto previsto dalla relazione \ref{
                                                  eq:cape}. Infine è stato ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
".
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please replace your first `[...]` with `\begin{document}` and add `\end{document}` at the end, so that the example becomes compilable. I get several errors, first among them is: `Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation with the subfig package.` In fact, when I remove `\usepackage{subfig}`, all errors disappear and the `\ref` works properly.

Comment: AFAICS, the package `subfig` [hasn't been maintained since 2005](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) (!). `subfig` is [known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13631/) to not be set up to work with `hyperref` properly.

Comment: Thank you @marquinho, the problem was with '''subfig'''.

Comment: Unrelated: what's `\centering` doing inside `equation`?

Comment: @marquinho On the other hand, `subfig` is compatible with several document classes that *aren't* compatible with `caption` (notably `revtex4-2` and `IEEEtran`), so it still has use cases.

Comment: @james Please do check my answer and consider accepting it (the green "checkmark") if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Pruning your code to get a proper [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), we find that the following reproduces your error:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % default since 2018, so probably redundant
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cape}
x<1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cape2}
x>0
\end{equation}

Inoltre si osservino le relazioni \ref{eq:cape} e \ref{eq:cape2}.

\end{document}
```

The code doesn't compile properly: The first of several errors is

```
Package subcaption 
Error: This package can't be used in cooperation with the subfig package.
```

In fact, the package `subfig` is very old and [appears](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) not to have been maintained since 2005 (!). This might be the reason why `subfig` is not set up [to work with `hyperref` properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13631/).

**EDIT**: @egreg points out the following: "`subfig` is compatible with several document classes that aren't compatible with `caption` (notably `revtex4-2` and `IEEEtran`), so it still has use cases."

Also, the maintainer(s) of `subcaption` have added the above warning that `subcaption` and `subfig` are incompatible. (Note that `subcaption` [is actively maintained](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).)

If we heed this warning and disable `subfig`, the code compiles and the references are processed properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % default since 2018, so probably redundant
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cape}
x<1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cape2}
x>0
\end{equation}

Inoltre si osservino le relazioni \ref{eq:cape} e \ref{eq:cape2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: example works with two equations]

To sum up:

- If you need subfigures (subfloats) in your document, you should avoid `subfig`, but `subcaption` is a better choice. Ultimately, this depends on your needs (not shown in this MWE).
- `subcaption` [requires pkg `caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13778/), which might be a problem with some document classes (**remember egreg's hint**).
- note that in general, **`\usepackage{hyperref}` must be loaded last in your preamble**, because `hyperref` has to adjust itself to all your other packages.