# How to create a grid of listings or grid of listings, mixed with figure (similar to `subfigure`, but not exclusive to `figure`)?

Tags: floats, listings, subfloats

From what I understand, there is some big difference between listing and figure. While I have not quite figured out what the differences are, I understand that I should not use them interchangeably.

Given that, how do I create a grid of multiple independent pieces of code, but as part of on overarching listing caption, similar to using `subfigure` to create a grid of figures?

Bonus question: What should I use in case I want to mix pictures and code (i.e. "`sublisting`" and `subfigure`)?

Specifically: I am using `minted`, the `listing` environment and `acmart`.

E.g., I want to arrange the following in a 2x2 grid:

```latex
\begin{listing}[thp]
  \caption{...}
  \begin{minted}
code1
  \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[thp]
  \caption{...}
  \begin{minted}
code2
  \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics{pic1}
  \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics{pic2}
  \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116884/90297
and this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451271/using-lstlisting-in-subfigure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using listings and subfigure together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/using-listings-and-subfigure-together)

Comment: @EladDen no, because, from that solution says to just put `listing` into `figure` and `subfigure`, and from what I understand, you are not supposed to put `listings` into `figures`.